# Xcode 8 Storyboard error

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I am working on building an app. Earlier I have used Xcode 7.1 at that time everything was working fine. Recently I have installed Xcode 8.0 as well and I have both the setups installed into in two different directories Xcode_7, Xcode_8 and I renamed the setup files as well. Everything was working fine but lately I am getting the following error while working with Xcode 8.

**"An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited "**

and the storyboard view objects are all gone empty like shown in the image but I am able to click on a specific view and still can see their properties defined through attributes inspector but nothing shows up in storyboard still I am able to build the project successfully but while loading it in simulator it says

**Unable to boot the iOS simulator**

I have followed few tips like reinstalling the Xcode , trashing the derived data from preferences. Nothing helped so far. Please let me know if anyone resolved this issue.

[Storyboard file ViewObjects all gone empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtOrZ.png)

**UPDATE**

I have found the fix with the help of apple forums here [Visit](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/189283)!.
**Disabling the  SIP (System Integrity Protection)** in my iMac which runs on El Capitan solved the issue however not sure disabling it will raise any further errors. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try This

> Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> click the
>   arrow to open in Finder -> And delete the content of that folder.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried that already and I mentioned the same too. The problem still persists, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh Prasanna, that's the  part of the solution.

Comment: Miraculous!! I was about to barge just to imagine rolling back my app xib by xib to a restore point to find out which was the offending one.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your mac, press cmd+R and open in recovery mode.

Open terminal and type command --> csrutil disable

restart mac..

open terminal--> sudo chmod 0777 / private / tmp

then run your xcode, simulator will work fine :)

Answer (score -1):

To all you Xcode 8 users out there:

Make sure you are running mac os sierra! It isn't said that being on el capitan will cause this problem. But I have updated to Sierra and everything works fine now!