# Storyboard not working as expected, Xcode 8.3 beta 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, beta

I installed Xcode 8.3 beta 3 in my mac and opened one of my old projects. I try to open storyboard, I got an unknown error,

> Internal error has occured : editing functionality may be limited

Its showing only BLUE empty boxes for labels, buttons, etc. Any fixes for this?

Comment: xcode 10.3 beta????

Comment: Sorry for that..edited

Comment: this bug has been in xcode since xcode 7. Try reporting the bug.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40102726/xcode-8-storyboard-error as well

Answer (score 0):

follow this:`Edit>>Convert>>To CurrentSwift Syntax` and resolve it. and deep clean your project and try.